# What does "mechanical parts" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In the IEEE essay "A New Standard for Quality Requirements", the author, Jørgen Bøegh, says;

> We needed to model systems that comprise communicating computer systems, and we wanted to include embedded
>   systems. So, we added a mechanical parts element
>   that covers mechanics, electronics, hydraulics, and
>   so on.

I wonder what "mechanical parts" mean here, so I search for my answer on google.
I get the explanation that mechanical parts are components in a machine, but I don't think this explanation is appropriate in this paragraph.

Then, I search for the meaning of "mechanical" on Cambridge Dictionary website.
I got these meanings of mechanical.

1. operated by a machine, or connected with machines or their parts
2. relating to movement, or to mechanics (= the study of the effect of physical forces on objects and their movement)
3. of machines or their parts
4. relating to engines or machines, or the way they operate
5. operated by a complicated system of parts or by a machine

But I still confused about which meaning of mechanical is appropriate in the paragraph and what "mechanical parts" means here.

Comment: The "mechanical parts" referred to are defined (partly) in the same sentence: mechanics, electronics, hydraulics. What the writer is saying (there is a missing hyphen) is that have added an element to the standard to cover the mechanical parts; ie. a mechanical-parts element.

Comment: "So, we added a mechanical parts element that covers mechanics, electronics, hydraulics, and so on."  What is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions you've quoted are correct and relevant (most if not all). The key to understanding the essay is to realise that when the author refers to "embedded systems" they're referring to computers embedded in machines. In other words they're discussing computers that don't just crunch numbers and display results, but that interact with the world in a physical way. Grouping electronics into this "mechanical" category is a little odd, but it makes sense in contrast to a definition of a computer that's all about information processing.

Comment: I think "electronics" is included under mechanical parts in order to cover the physical aspects of the electronics (PCBs, soldering, mounting, perhaps manufacturing processes, etc) rather than just the functional (electronic) aspects.

Comment: @JamesRandom that's a good point. They'd certainly be regarded as mechanical aspects of an electronic device when considering failure modes so the authors could be thinking of the site of things.